# My batch file script to run coded UI test is not working

Tags: batch-file, automation, coded-ui-tests

So I have a coded UI test that works fine. I've create a batch file script so that i can run in windows task scheduler. It keeps showing "Failed"

This is what I tried:

```
cd /
cd "C:\Users\alish\source\repos\CodedUITestProject6\CodedUITestProject6\obj\Debug\CodedUITestProject6.dll "



@echo off
set max=.set count=.
echo starting test execution
echo =======================
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:C:\Users\alish\source\repos\CodedUITestProject6\CodedUITestProject6\obj\Debug\CodedUITestProject6.dll/test:CodedUITestMethod1



echo all done
@exit
```

Comment: Should there not be space before `/test:` and why `cd` to your dir if you do full path in the mtest.exe string anyway?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks for you reply.There should be a space or shouldn't? Anyways i've tried with and without space. Same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much sense in doing the `cd /` nor the need to cd to dir if you put it path anyway. Also I recall you need a space before `/test:` So just do:

```
@echo off
set max=. && set count=.

 cd /d "%userprofile%\source\repos\CodedUITestProject6\CodedUITestProject6\obj\Debug\"
 echo starting test execution
 echo =======================
 Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:CodedUITestProject6.dll /test:CodedUITestMethod1

echo all done
pause
```